# Xcodebuild- Travis CI can't archive a project that uses cocoapods due to code signing error?

Tags: cocoapods, travis-ci, xcodebuild, codesign

Trying to use Travis CI to build, archive and distribute my Ad Hoc app builds through Crashlytics (Fabric).
Having an issue with the code signing process though, as it attempts to code sign the cocoapods I am using.
Here is the output:

```
=== ARCHIVE ===
  xcodebuild archive My Cool App - AdHoc
    Pods / Bolts (AdHoc)
      ✗ Check dependencies (16 ms)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile does not match bundle identifier: The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“My Cool App (AdHoc)”) has an AppID of “com.nitwitstudios.mycoolapp” which does not match your bundle identifier “org.cocoapods.Bolts”.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this issue with a project that has `use_frameworks!` enabled.

The temporary workaround I found for this was changing the code signing identity for any iOS SDK for all of my Cocoapod frameworks to default so that it was `iOS Distribution`:

[image: Code Signing]

This doesn't really seem like a permanent solution though - this gets overwritten  anytime I `pod update`.

Comment: Yes, the correct answer was in fact removing 'use_frameworks!' from the pod file. Seems like that is the only workaround for the time being.

Comment: @JamesHickman: That's not actually possible when you're using Swift, unfortunately - still need to use this workaround.